# Converting a number (non-currency) value to a text entry

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Easy enough concept, but I have no idea where to start when it comes to creating a UDF, which is the only thing I can find any mention of.  I have a column that populates on source sheets with either a 1 or 2.  I want to do something so that all of the "1's" shows as one text entry("AA" for example) and all "2's" show as a different entry(say "BB"). Is this possible without a UDF; and if not then is there any advice on where to start?

Comment: Create a table with two columns: the number and the matching text.  Use VLOOKUP() to translate the numbers to their matching text value.

Comment: I didn't know I could get VLOOKUP to actually replace the values in the source column.  I get just a plain old vlookup, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Comment: Sorry - missed that there were only two numbers...

Comment: How do the 1 and 2 get populated?

Comment: Well it's going to end up being more than two values, probably four for what I'm going to need to do with it. It's populated similarly to some of my other projects that you've commented on (a template is copied and specific information is pulled from a master sheet to the copy of the template). So it just pulls the info from one sheet and copies it into another.  It's stupid really; everyone knows what the codes mean, but someone higher than any of us locally doesn't want to expend the brain power of doing the conversion in his head. :)

Comment: in that case you could maybe just perform the mapping when you copy over the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom formatting for this.  Right-click the column in question and choose "Format Cells."  In the dialog, choose "Custom" and in the box at the top enter:

```
[=1]"AA";[=2]"BB";General
```

This assumes that the "1" or "2" is the sole content of the cell.  Any other number or text will display in the General format.

Comment: This works just right. I figured there had to be an easier way to get this accomplished. Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm on my way back at the moment, will that work if I needed to add in anything else (eg. [=3]"CC") or is it only good for two values?

Comment: Alas, it's only good for two plus a default.  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you as well.  It is a conditional statement that will reference one cell the check if there is content, if not then it will put the word "None" in, otherwise it will put the contents of the cell.

=IF((Sheet1!J1089)="","None",Sheet1!J1089)

Answer (score 0):

Just to update anyone else that may be interested. I have a solution that I am using. Had to go the vba route, but I've got it set up so that my macro for running reports runs the following:

```
Sub Conversion()
  Dim X As Long, DBCodes() As String
  DBCodes = Split("AA,BB,CC", ",")
  For X = 1 To 3
    Columns("H").Replace X, DBCodes(X - 1), xlWhole
  Next
End Sub
```

I can change the split values and the line after for as many more values as I need replacing, though it would take fiddling with to find the point where too many values would make it impractical.  Also, it makes a world of difference where I put in the line to run this; found the best spot though and even the reports that are 600+ rows the conversion only adds a couple seconds.